# Problems trying to deploy a web application

Tags: java, war

I have a problem with creating web services from my entity classes by using netbeans. Actually I have a javaee project which works on weblogic 10g, oracle database 10g and uses JSF 2.1 with primefaces. It works quite good.

But when it comes to add web services to my project I come across with

> Deployment failed. The message was: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ContainerListener
>   C:\Users\Developer\Documents\NetBeansProjects\IBB_Projeler\nbproject\build-impl.xml:294: The module has not been deployed.

As I add the web services, my web.xml becomes:

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>Multiple packages, separated by semicolon(;), can be specified in param-value</description>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>Resources</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            3000
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <ejb-local-ref>
        <ejb-ref-name>ProjectsFacade</ejb-ref-name>
        <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
        <local>com.ibb.entity.facades.ProjectsFacadeLocal</local>
        <ejb-link>projetakip-ejb.jar#ProjectsFacade</ejb-link>
    </ejb-local-ref>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jpeg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <ejb-local-ref>
        <ejb-ref-name>ProjectsFacade1</ejb-ref-name>
        <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
        <local>com.ibb.entity.facades.ProjectsFacadeLocal</local>
        <ejb-link>projetakip-ejb.jar#ProjectsFacade</ejb-link>
    </ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-local-ref>
        <ejb-ref-name>ProjectsFacade2</ejb-ref-name>
        <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
        <local>com.ibb.entity.facades.ProjectsFacadeLocal</local>
        <ejb-link>projetakip-ejb.jar#ProjectsFacade</ejb-link>
    </ejb-local-ref>
    <persistence-unit-ref>
        <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence-factory</persistence-unit-ref-name>
        <persistence-unit-name>projetakip-warPU</persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-unit-ref>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/index.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Basically it adds the following:

```html
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>Multiple packages, separated by semicolon(;), can be specified in param-value</description>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>Resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I searched a little bit, in some forums they say to add related jars. I have added jersey-server, jsr311-api, asm3.1,jersey-gf-server, and jersey-servlet.

But the problem still occurs, if someone could help I would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you don't have the enough jars for Jersey. Please add them in your WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I have written my jars there, what do you think which jars am I missing?

Comment: Search the jar that should contain `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerListener` class and make sure it is deployed in your war file.

Comment: I have added the related jars but the problem still occurs. Couldn't find a suitable solution.